# Prove $\mu(\liminf A_n)=\mu(\limsup A_n)$. Problem 2.87in Problems in Real and Functional Analysis by Alberto Torchinsky.

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

**Question:** Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space and $\{A_n\}\subset \mathscr{A}$ such that $\sum_n \mu(A_n-A_{n+1})<\infty$. Prove that $\mu(\liminf A_n)=\mu(\limsup A_n)$.

**Description:**
I have already shown that
$$\mu(\liminf A_n)\leq \liminf \mu(A_n)\leq \limsup\mu(A_n)\leq \mu(\limsup A_n).$$
And the solution in the book shows $\mu(\liminf A_n)\geq \limsup \mu(A_n)$ (which only finds a lower bound of the least element) then concludes, which I think is wrong because we haven't found any upper bound of $\mu(\limsup A_n)$.

The proof of $\mu(\liminf A_n)\geq \limsup \mu(A_n)$ is by noting that
$$
A_n-(A_n-A_{n+1})-(A_{n+1}-A_{n+2})-\cdots-(A_{n+m-1}-A_{n+m})=\cap_{k=n}^{n+m} A_k.
$$
Then let $m\to\infty$ and $n\to\infty$.

But how to prove $\mu(\limsup A_n)\leq \liminf \mu(A_n)$? I can't find such observation in this case.

Any ideas and answers might help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer does not follow the method in the book.
Verify that $\lim \sup_n A_n \subseteq (\lim \inf A_n) \cup (\lim \sup (A_n\setminus A_{n+1})$. This inclusion always holds and it is purely set theoretic. To finish the proof just note that $P(\lim \sup (A_n\setminus A_{n+1})=0$ by Borel-Cantelli Lemma.