# $\limsup (A_{n+1}-A_n)=\limsup (A_{n}-A_{n+1})$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Let $\{A_n\}$ be a sequence of sets.** Note that "$-$" here means "$\backslash$", the set operator, $A-B=A\cap B^c$.

I think $\limsup (A_{n+1}-A_n)=\limsup (A_{n}-A_{n+1})$. The reason is that they both equal to $\limsup A_n - \liminf A_n$. Here is my "proof" (please help me check it).

1. First $\limsup A_n - \liminf A_n = \limsup (A_{n+1}-A_n)$. 1.1 For $x\in \limsup A_n\cap (\liminf A_n)^c=\limsup A_n\cap \limsup A_n^c$, given any $N$, there exists $n_1>N$ such that $x\in A_{n_1}^c$. There exists $n_2>n_1$ such that $x\in A_{n_2}$. By well-ordering principle, there exists a least $n_2>n_1$ satisfies $x\in A_{n_2}$. Then $x\in A_{n_2}-A_{n_2-1}$, which shows $\limsup A_n - \liminf A_n \subset \limsup (A_{n+1}-A_n)$. 1.2 on the other side, if $x\in \limsup (A_{n+1}-A_n)$, then for any $N$, there exists $n>N$ such that $x\in A_{n+1}$ and $x\in A_n^c$. From the definition, $x\in \limsup A_{n}$ and $x\in \limsup A_n^c=(\liminf A_n)^c$. Therefore $x\in \limsup A_n - \liminf A_n$.
2. From 1, take $A_n$ be $A_n^c$ (change the notation), then $\text{LHS}=\limsup A_n^c-\liminf A_n^c=(\liminf A_n)^c-(\limsup A_n)^c=(\liminf A_n)^c\cap (\limsup A_n)=\limsup A_n - \liminf A_n$, stays the same. While $\text{RHS}=\limsup (A_{n+1}^c-A_{n}^c)=\limsup (A_n-A_{n+1})$. Since LHS=RHS, we have $\limsup A_n - \liminf A_n=\limsup (A_n-A_{n+1})$.

2*. The same proof in 1 also could prove 2.

Therefore, I think in general $\limsup (A_n-A_{n+1})=\limsup (A_{n+1}-A_n)$. I am not so sure because I couldn't find anyone state this on the internet (google).

---

Actually the 1. is from [this question 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283028/prove-limsupa-n-backslash-liminfa-n-limsupa-n1-backslash-a-n?rq=1) and I need the latter because of [this question 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4538466/prove-mu-liminf-a-n-mu-limsup-a-n-problem-2-87in-problems-in-real-and-f).

Any ideas or references of the equation might help!!

---

If this is true, could someone prove it directly?

Comment: $\limsup_n a_n=\liminf_n (-a_n)$

Comment: @Surb Your $A_{n+1}-A_n$ is always empty, since $A_{n+1} \subseteq A_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x\notin\limsup(A_{n+1}\setminus A_n)\Longleftrightarrow\exists N\quad\forall n\ge N\quad x\in A_n\lor x\notin A_{n+1}$$
and

$[\forall n\ge N\quad x\in A_n\lor x\notin A_{n+1}]\Longleftrightarrow$$[x\in\left(\bigcap_{n\ge N}A_n\right)\lor\exists N'\ge N\quad x\in\left(\bigcap_{N\le n<N'}A_n\right)\cap\left(\bigcap_{n\ge N'}A_n^c\right)]$

hence

$$x\notin\limsup(A_{n+1}\setminus A_n)\Longleftrightarrow(\exists N\quad\forall n\ge N\quad x\in A_n)\lor(\exists N'\quad\forall n\ge N'\quad x\in A_n^c).$$
Since the RHS is symmetric in $A_n,A_n^c$,

$$\begin{align}x\notin\limsup(A_{n+1}\setminus A_n)&\Longleftrightarrow x\notin\limsup(A_{n+1}^c\setminus A_n^c)\\&\Longleftrightarrow x\notin\limsup(A_n\setminus A_{n+1}).
\end{align}$$